# How plot own graph in Sage?

Tags: graph-theory, sage

> How to draw a Graph in Sage-Math :

Suppose I have a Graph G with 4 vertices v1,v2,v3,v4 such that v1 is adjacent to v2 and  v3 is adjacent to v4.

I wrote the following code in SageMath which did not work:

> G=Graph({1:[2],3:[4]})

But the code is showing  **Traceback Error**.

Can someone kindly comment on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a lot more detail about your error, this would be very hard to answer.  In any case, this syntax should work - [see this example](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzzsHUvSizI0Kg2tIo2itUxtoo2ia3V5OUqyMkv0fDQBACVYgkK&lang=sage).

```
H=Graph({1:[2],3:[4]})
plot(H)
```

[image]

Comment: We would need to know a lot more about your specific setup (which interface, which version of Sage, etc.) before being able to help further.